# Check if String Contains an Emoji in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby, here is how you can check for a substring in a string:

```
str = "hello world"
str.include?("lo")
=> true
```

When I am attempting to save an emoji in a text column in a rails application (the text column within a mysql database is `utf8`), it comes back with this error:

> Incorrect string value: \xF0\x9F\x99\x82

For my situation in a rails application, it suffices to see if an emoji is present in the submitted text.  If an emoji is present: raise a validation error.  Example:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  validate :cannot_contain_emojis

  private

  def cannot_contain_emojis
    if my_column.include?("/\xF0")
      errors.add(:my_column, 'Cannot include emojis")
    end 
  end
end
```

**Note:** The reason I am checking for `\xF0` is because according to [this site](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode), it appears that all, or most, emoji's begin with this signature.

This however does not work.  It continues to return `false` even when it is true.  I'm pretty sure the issue is that my include statement doesn't work because the emoji is not converted to bytes for the comparison.

**Question**
How can I make a validation to check that an emoji is not passed in?

- Example bytes for a smiley face in UTF8: `\xF0\x9F\x99\x82`

Comment: Can you explain this? `my_column.include?(".include?("\\xF0")") `. 1) it's a syntax error 2) why do you check if the string includes "include"? :/

Comment: @Ursus thanks I updated the question code.

Comment: Yoru code is not syntactically valid Ruby code. Even the very basic syntax highlighting on [so] recognizes that.

Comment: You kind of answered your own question, you are trying to determine if the bytes of a string contain a set of bytes, but that isn't how the `include?` method works. It looks at the code points in the argument string and sees if those code points are in the source string.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing "emoji" with "UTF-8 multibyte character", as those are *anything* not in 7-bit ASCII, including € and é.

Comment: Are you using MySQL as your database? Its utf8 encoding isn’t really utf8, you should use utf8mb4. See e.g. https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: @matt I am using mysql.  That article you reference is useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Emoji` Unicode property to test for Emoji using a [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html), something like this:

```rb
def cannot_contain_emojis
  if /\p{Emoji}/ =~ my_column
    errors.add(:my_column, 'Cannot include emojis')
  end 
end
```

[Unicode® Technical Standard #51 "UNICODE EMOJI"](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/) contains a [more sophisticated regex](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#EBNF_and_Regex):

```regex
\p{RI} \p{RI} 
| \p{Emoji} 
  ( \p{EMod} 
  | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
  | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  (\x{200D} \p{Emoji}
    ( \p{EMod} 
    | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
    | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  )*
```

[Note: some of those properties are not implemented in Onigmo / Ruby.]

However, checking for Emojis probably not going to be enough. It is pretty clear that your text processing is somehow broken at some point. And if it is broken by an Emoji, then there is a chance it will also be broken by my name, or the name of Ruby's creator 松本 行弘, or by the completely normal English word “naïve”.

Instead of playing a game of whack-a-mole trying to detect every Emoji, mathematical symbol, Arabic letter, typographically correct punctuation mark, etc., it would be much better simply the fix the text processing.

Comment: Note that `\p{Emoji}` will match numbers (e.g. `8`). `\p{Emoji_Presentation}` seems like it's doing a better job at just matching emojis.

Answer (score 1):

I found Jörg's solution was only working when passing in the string itself and not a variable. Not sure why that is.

```rb
/\p{Emoji}/ =~ ""
=> 0

value = "1f383"
=> "1f383"
/\p{Emoji}/ =~ value
=> 0

/\p{Emoji}/ =~ "hello"
=> nil
```

Regardless I'd recommend using the [unicode-emoji gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode-emoji), as its approach is comprehensive. Its [source code and documentation](https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-emoji) can be found on GitHub.

Comment: This will work, the only thing missing is special characters around the emoji unicode value: `value = "\u{1F383}"`